# XSLT rounding attributes for SVG optimization

Tags: xslt, svg, number-formatting

I need to reduce the numeric precision, and minimum exponent of SVG attributes to save space.

Input:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250">
 <circle cx="125.1111" cy="125.2222" r="124.9999" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Output:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250">
 <circle cx="125.1" cy="125.2" r="125.0" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

What stylesheet will achieve the result?
Any thoughts on the safety of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[.=number()]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#.#')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<svg width="250" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="125.1" cy="125.2" r="125" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Just a word of warning that the precise way in which format-number does rounding is underspecified in XSLT 1.0 - this is corrected in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Michael Kay: +1 Completely accurate, although results are equal for MSXSL, Altova, Xalan XSLT 1.0 processors; Saxon, Altova, XQSharp XSLT 2.0 processor and "in between" Oracle XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

On the applicability:

Without proper analysis it's not going to work for all cases, but it usually works fine to chop off some decimals and hoping for the best. Truncating to one decimal in gradients (usually defined in objectBoundingBox space) can give poor results, same with other places using objectBoundingBox units (such attribute values are usually in the range [0..1]). Anything else mostly depends on the current transform (CTM) and what 'viewBox' is used on the root svg element.

Comment: On second thoughts, I should probably only apply this to path d elements and such, since they're the low hanging fruit. Rotation angles and matrices could go way off. There won't be a viewBox.